# what the meaning of FOR in a label tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In HTML, What's the purpose of the attribute **for** in the **label** tag.

```
<label for = "Name">Name: </label>
<% = Html.TextBox("Name")%>
```

In the above sample, why the label tag has a for = "Name" attribute? To mark their association??? If I don't put for what gonna happen?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `for` attribute specifies which form element the label is bound to.

The `label` element allows the user to give focus to a form element by clicking on an associate label. If you do not use the `for` attribute, this association will not be made.

Comment: so basically apart from attaching the focus to the input it is useless?

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the label, you may for instance **check or uncheck a checkbox / radio button**. The `for` attribute tells what checkbox the label belongs to.

A complete example is available at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp.

Answer (score 4):

If the user clicks on the `label`, and the `for` attribute matches that `id` of the respective control, it will toggle the control.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the same thing by including the form element within the "bound" label element.  It's nice when you can't or don't want to give IDs to your elements.

```
<label>
   My Label
   <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Comment: I never knew this was possible. Is this by any chance HTML5 only?